# Equivalent statements concerning Countable Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, intuition

While reading I came across the following theorem.

> Suppose $A$ is a set. The following statements are
>   equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is countable.
> 2. Either $A = \varnothing $ or there is a function $f:\mathbf{Z^+}\to A$ that is onto.
> 3. There is a function $f : A →\mathbf{Z^+}$ that is one-to-one.

Could you please explain how can we understand the equivalence of the above statements on a more intuitive level? Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of 'countable' in (1)?

Comment: Are you equipped with a particular definition of countable before encountering this statement?

Comment: Yes to me a set  $A$ is countable if there is a bijection from either $\mathbf{Z^+}$ to $A$ or from $I_n = \{i\in\mathbf{Z^+}|i\leq n\}$ to $A$ for some $n\in\mathbf{Z^+}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An onto function $S \to T$ intuitively means $T$ "lines up" (is in bijection with) part of $S$, and a one-to-one function $S \to T$ intuitively means $S$ "lines up" with part of $T$. Thus both 2 and 3 are saying $A$ "lines up" with part of $\mathbb{Z}^+$. This "alignment" gives you the way to count $A$.